are solutions to linear system isomorphic to affine space?
I have trouble in my textbook Elementary algebraic geometry(Klaus hulek), here I cite.

Example 0.4. The simplest possible algebraic subset of $\Bbb A_k^n$ is one given by a set of linear equations. Such an algebraic set is called an
affine sub space, and is itself isomorphic to an affine space.

・k is algebraically closed field
・$\Bbb A_k^n=\{(a_1,...,a_n) |a_i\in k\}$
・A subset $Y\subset\Bbb A_k^n$ is called algebraic set in $\Bbb A_k^n$ if there is a subset $T\subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that
$Y=\{P\in\Bbb A_k^n(a_1,...,a_n) |f(P)=0$ for all $f\in T\}$.
I think this example indicating algebraic set $S=\{x\in \Bbb A_k^n |Ax=b\}$ for some $m\times n $ matirix $A$ and $1\times n$ matrix $b$.
And I could figure out that $S=x_0+W$ where $x_0$ is any element of $S$ and $W$ is solution space of $Ax=0$.
This correspond to the definition of affine subspace in linear algebra, so I think this interpretation is correct.
However I can't undestand it is isomorphic to an affine space.
Does this mean that there is an affine space with proper dimension and isomorphic to S?
Even if this is true, how can I prove it?

Perhaps this post is helpful. $S=x_0+W$ is not a vector space for $x_0\neq 0$, but isomorphic to one, and hence to an affine space. See also this post.

Yes, your suggestion is true. Here are some hints that might help to prove it. First, suppose that $W$ has dimension $d$. Try to find an isomorphism $\mathbb A^d \rightarrow W$ e.g. by choosing a basis of $W$. Next, show that the map $W \rightarrow S$ defined by $x \mapsto x + x_0$ is an isomorphism.

Problem solved!
thanks for your help!!
